# Receiving Emails in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, email

I have found a way to send mails in HTML using Javascript.

```
function sendMail()
{
    var msg ="mailto:"
            +escape($('#receiver').val())
            +"?cc="
            +escape($('#cc').val())
            +"&subject="
            +escape($('#subject').val())
            +"&body="
            +escape($('#message').val());
    window.location.href = msg;
}
```

However, I haven't found a way to actually RECEIVE mail, only send.

Any way to do this?

Comment: This doesn't actually *send* email, it just opens up the default email client's email composition window *if there is a default email client*.

Comment: yes, I know. I haven't figured out how to do it purely on the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Receiving e-mails is not something you can do entirely client-side.  You need a server-side component to do this.

I should also warn you that the way you're using `mailto:` isn't entirely standard, and won't work everywhere.